# upload file on HTTP server using POST gives 0 for HttpFileCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http-post

I am trying to upload file on HTTP server using POST but when I call it gives

**uploadFile.Count = 0** amd does not go into if statement. File path is correct.

**client code**

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileToUpload = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Ricky_Martin_Livin_la.mp3");
            string uploadUrl = "http://localhost/soundcheck/uploadfiles.aspx";
            //string uploadUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/musicapp/handle_upload.php";
            FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);
            req.Method = "POST"; // you might use "POST"
            req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
            req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];

            // Get data from upload file to inData 
            int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, int.Parse(rdr.Length.ToString()));

            // put data into request stream
            reqStream.Write(inData, 0, int.Parse(rdr.Length.ToString()));

            rdr.Close();
            req.GetResponse();

            // after uploading close stream 
            reqStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Server code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class uploadfiles : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LogInFile("First");
            HttpFileCollection uploadFile = Request.Files;
            LogInFile("Second");
            LogInFile(uploadFile.Count.ToString());
            if (uploadFile.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFile[0];
                LogInFile("Thrid");
                System.IO.Stream inStream = postedFile.InputStream;
                LogInFile("Forth");
                byte[] fileData = new byte[postedFile.ContentLength];
                LogInFile("Fifth");
                inStream.Read(fileData, 0, postedFile.ContentLength);
                LogInFile("Sixth");
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + postedFile.FileName);
            }        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Message : " +ex.Message);
            sb.AppendLine("Source : " + ex.Source);
            sb.AppendLine("StackTrace : " + ex.StackTrace);
            sb.AppendLine("InnerException : " + ex.InnerException);
            sb.AppendLine("ToString : " + ex.ToString());

            LogInFile(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    public void LogInFile(string str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\expfile.txt"))
        {            
            sb.AppendLine("= = = = = =");
            sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        sb.AppendLine(str);
        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\expfile.txt"))
        {
            outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

In server code I write these Logs to track if there is any error or error at which line.

In Server code it gives  uploadFile.Count = 0 and does not go in 
In Debug mode client code executes successfully but gives this message on page

You can see from Server/Client code .. there is no DB involved.

[image]

Comment: please post your html form. Also login failed for sa is asp.net failing to login into your db

Comment: You can see from code there is not DB involved .. or DB access code even

Comment: Well the error you posted is db related. Maybe the code is somewhere else in the project. Maybe global.asax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the database credentials which you have supplied are not correct.

Comment: You can see from code there is not DB involved .. or DB access code even

Comment: He's referring to the message and not the code.